# Meteor accounts-ui dropdown behavior when embedded in the navbar dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to place the standard Meteor accounts-ui into a navbar dropdown with the cog icon as shown in the screenshot and code snippet below. However, two issues arise:

1. Before signing in, there is an odd extra whitespace on the right side. After signing in, it aligns fine.
2. After a single click on any of the elements in the dropdown, the dropdown immediately closes. This is fine when I click `Sign in with Google` or `Sign in`, but it should not do that when I click into the text input fields, `Forgot password` or `Create account`.

How can I address the above behaviors accordingly while still using the `accounts-ui` package? For instance, is there some sort of JS code I can use to override the behavior to fix #2? Thanks!

[image: Before logging in]
[image: After logging in]

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="account-dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>{{loginText}}</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><b>{{> loginButtons align="right"}}</b></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: I tried what I posted in the question. Did you mean to ask about something else?

Answer (score 1):

[`ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3`](https://atmospherejs.com/ian/accounts-ui-bootstrap-3) provides a Bootstrap dropdown out of the box. The code will look like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
        {{> loginButtons}}
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

But this does not display a cog-wheel.  If you want to override the default dropdown link to a custom one, you need to override the template in the package. AFAIK, Meteor core doesn't have an easy way to do this, but you can use [`aldeed:template-extension`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-template-extension) to achieve this quite simply. First copy the template code from the [`accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` repo](https://github.com/ianmartorell/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3), then create a new template with similar content but different name:

```
<template name="my_loginButtonsLoggedInDropdown">
  <li id="login-dropdown-list" class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown">
      ... custom content here ...
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu col-sm-3">
      {{#if inMessageOnlyFlow}}
        {{> _loginButtonsMessages}}
      {{else}}
        {{#if inChangePasswordFlow}}
          {{> _loginButtonsChangePassword}}
        {{else}}
          {{> _loginButtonsLoggedInDropdownActions}}
        {{/if}}
      {{/if}}
    </div>
  </li>
</template>
```

Then use

```
Template.my_loginButtonsLoggedInDropdown.replaces("_loginButtonsLoggedInDropdown")
```

It will replace the template, but still use the helpers and events from the original template.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've used `ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3`, and it looks great. Unfortunately, I had to revert back to the standard `accounts-ui` to get the forceApprovalPrompt to work.